# Custom select directive outside of controller scope - generating empty option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here's a general idea of what I am doing:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>...</head>

<body>

<select class="form-control" ng-model="change_group" change-group>
    <!-- options loaded in from Symfony/twig -->
    <option value='0'>lala</option>
    <option value='1'>bla</option>
</select>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When that all loads, the directive seems to work, and I can get it to trigger whenever the select is changed; but it's creating an empty option, and I can't seem to get it to pre-select an existing option, instead of it generating an empty one and having that be default.

```
myapp.directive('changeGroup', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: { },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.change_group = 0;
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {            
            ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
                console.log('changed');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When I load the page, the desired option (0) flickers for a split second and then goes back to the empty option.

This is what the select looks like, after angular inserts that empty option:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-touched" ng-model="change_group" change-group="">
    <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
    <option value="0">Public</option>
    <option value="1">xil3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What happens if you set the value in the link function instead of the directive controller?

Comment: It doesn't even flicker (like in the controller); so it doesn't seem like it attempts to set it.

Comment: Updated my question to illustrate what the select looks like, after that empty option is inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize to a **string**; not a number.

Also use no scope; not isolate scope.

```
angular.module("app",[]).directive('changeGroup', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: "ngModel",
        //Do not use isolate scope
        //scope: {},
        controller: function($scope,$element) {
            //Initialize to string
            $scope.change_group = '1';
            //Not to a number
            //$scope.change_group = 1;
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {            
            ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
                console.log('changed');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vLuaj1o/).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `scope: {}` as that creates a new isolate scope and I think you are losing your `change_group` scope variable.

Comment: I removed that, but it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Huh, weird. I did that and it started working. I was testing it in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Can I see your JSFiddle?

Comment: I'll post a link when I get back home if you haven't figured this one out yet.

Comment: Still can't get it going

Comment: Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n03vd83p/). Uncomment the `scope: {}` in the directive and it stops working.